# Is there any solution about UIActivityIndicatorView in synchronous process?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiactivityindicatorview

In a method, i start the UIActivityIndicatorView to start.
and then use NSXMLParser to get the node information from the XML with synchronization.
After finished parse, i want stop the UIActivityIndicatorView.
My propose is to appear the UIActivityIndicatorView when parse the XML, but it doesn't work.
Any ideas? Thanks.

```
- (void)ButtonTouch{

[activityIndicator startAnimating];
    /*get the login result*/
    loginXMLDealer *loginxmldealer = [[loginXMLDealer alloc] init];
    loginxmldealer.username = usernameField.text;
    loginxmldealer.password = passwordField.text;
    [loginxmldealer loginResult];
    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    if ([loginxmldealer.rspCode isEqualToString: @"0001"]) {

        UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Please check your passport." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [errorAlert show];
        [errorAlert release];
    }
    else {
        [self presentModalViewController:self.dataMainController animated:YES]; 

    }
    [loginxmldealer release];
}
```

Comment: Show us the code you have already. Then we can help you figure out what you need to do/change/add/remove.

Comment: ok.I have already edit my question.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
- (void)buttonAction
{
  [activityIndicator startAnimating];
  [self performSelector:@selector(doWork) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
}

- (void)doWork
{
  //Do your xml parsing here...
}
```

This gives the UI the chance to update by returning control to the runloop before you block the main thread. Depending on your task, it might be a good idea to use a background thread or Grand Central Dispatch instead, so that the rest of the UI doesn't block and you can give a user the option to cancel the process (which is impossible with the simple approach above).

Comment: For the animation to work, you have to do the processing in a background thread or GCD. This code will let it appear, but it will not animate.

Comment: It will animate, because UIActivityIndicator uses a background thread itself for the animation.